# NSString value not persistent

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am declaring class variable of type NSString in my "class.h":

```
@interface class : NSObject<GADInterstitialDelegate, 
GADBannerViewDelegate, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate, 
GADNativeAppInstallAdLoaderDelegate, GADNativeContentAdLoaderDelegate>
{
   ...
   NSString* appId;
}
```

I the "class.mm" file In function "a" i am assigning a value to the variable:

```
appId = [[dic objectForKey:@"appid"] stringValue]
```

The string value at this point is correct.

The problem happen when other function call - function "b".

```
[GoogleMobileAdsMediationTestSuite presentWithAppID:appId onViewController:rootViewController delegate:nil];
```

when i try to use this appId - it doesn't contain the assigned, instead I assume it contain a memory address.

How can I keep the value of `appId` in all future references?

Comment: can you add some additional code

Comment: Checking at this code tell me there is no issue. Search for `appId` and check if it's value is updated some where else, also show code were you are displaying to value of appId.

Comment: Is appId a member variable? If yes, are you calling the functions a and b on the same object?

Comment: @rptwsthi can it be that the app id value is being cleared when dic (dictionary) is being cleared? So when the net function calls and dic is no longer valid the appId value points to unfilled address?

Comment: Please show the whole definition. How is that "class variable" declared?

Comment: @Sulthan added the full variable declaration

Comment: @MichaelA You have got it i think, can you try (not deleting) test and let me know the result.

Comment: @rptwsthi So i got it to work by doing this:  appId = [[dic objectForKey:@"appid"] retain]; So that means that the appId my assumption was correct and appId was referencing the "dic" object all this time? The question is how can i detach the appId from the "dic" object so it will stay alive even when the object is cleard?

Comment: You know how, see when you assign value it just keep reference form original object but soon you initialize new object with `new` `alloc` or call retain, it's a copy of original. You can keep retain or use `NSString *entityName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[dic objectForKey:@"appid"] stringValue]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know how, see when you assign value it just keep reference form original object but soon you initialize new object with `new` `alloc` or call retain, it's a copy of original. You can keep retain or use

```
NSString *entityName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[dic objectForKey:@"appid"] stringValue]];`
```

Or may be you can define `appId` as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *appId;
```

in interface and, refer it with `self.appId`.

Answer (score 0):

> So i got it to work by doing this: `appId = [[dic objectForKey:@"appid"] retain];`

If that compiles, it means that you've turned off ARC (automatic reference counting) for that file or for your whole project. There's little reason to do that these days, especially if you're not very familiar with the manual reference counting rules. The best solution is almost certainly to turn ARC back on and remove the `retain` call.

> So that means that the appId my assumption was correct and appId was referencing the "dic" object all this time? The question is how can i detach the appId from the "dic" object so it will stay alive even when the object is cleard?

Basically, you were assigning a string to `appId` without retaining the string. When the dictionary you got it from was released, it also released all the objects that it contained, including the string that `appId` pointed to. With manual reference counting, which you are apparently using, you have to `retain` any objects that you keep a reference to, and `release` those objects when you no longer need that reference. If you create an object with `alloc`/`init` or `new` or `copy` (or some variant of those), you don't need to `retain` that object, but you do need to `release` it. You can read more about it in [*Memory Management Rules*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH27-SW3).

Comment: So in case i alloc / init to the variable i still need to release it, so its quite the same as retain

Comment: Yes, when you create an object, you need to release it. If you get an object that someone else created, you need to retain it until you're done with it, and then release it. But again, there's little point in doing that yourself — the compiler can do it better and more reliably than you can, so unless there's some real reason not to, just turn on ARC and let the compiler handle it for you.

Answer (score -2):

Try to alloc appID variable like: [NSString string] in "class.m" and then you can change value of this variable.
You try to assign value to null

Comment: You can't change the string of the NSString you get back from `[NSString string]` — you can only replace it with a different string. And if you're just going to replace it, there's no point in allocating it in the first place.